# Relative Date Base with Dateutil

Tags: python, date, python-dateutil

I'm trying to parse relative dates (today at 4:00, tomorrow at 10:00, yesterday at 8:00, etc.) with Python using dateutil.parse but would like to supply a "today" date to actually use as a base.  The issue is I might be looking at content created yesterday but still has "today" in its content, so dateutil.parse doesn't parse out the true DateTime.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`dateutil.parser.parse()` function has `default` parameter](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) but it doesn't parse relative human-readable dates. You could use [`parsedatetime` module](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) for that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime # $ pip install parsedatetime

today = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
calendar= parsedatetime.Calendar()
for timestring in [
        "today at 4:00", 
        "tomorrow at 10:00", 
        "yesterday at 8:00"]:
    d, parsed_as = calendar.parseDT(timestring, today)
    assert parsed_as == 3 # as datetime
    print(d)
```

#### Output

```
2015-01-01 04:00:00
2015-01-02 10:00:00
2014-12-31 08:00:00
```